# What does the `里` mean in `这些狗里有一只穿红色的毛衣`?

Tags: mandarin, word

In the following sentence:

```
这些狗里有一只穿红色的毛衣
```

What does the `里` mean? I think the sentence means something like `The dogs wear red sweaters.` But why does it require `里` there and what meaning does it add?

I'm learning about simplified mandarin language, but would like to know if it differs from the traditional in how it is used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means `one of these dogs wears a red sweater`. `...里` literally means `in/among ...`, and it is followed by 有一只, which means `there is one`. Hence the whole sentence translates literally as `Among these dogs there is one wearing a red sweater`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Then `Among these dogs there are two wearing a red sweater.` is translated into `这些狗里有两只穿红色的毛衣`, right? (Side Topic: if two dogs wear a sweater, should it be written in `wearing a red sweater` or `wearing red sweaters`?)

Comment: Yes, it's exactly '这些狗里有两只穿红色的毛衣'. (I would say 'wearing red sweaters')

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is the same in traditional Chinese. In traditional Chinese, the style is different, 里 => 裡.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence was written in Traditional Chinese, you might find it easier to understand:

這些狗裏有一隻穿紅色的毛衣.

and it means:

這群狗中, 有一隻穿紅色的毛衣.

Even in the original sentence, I prefer "中" or "當中" because it is less confusing than "里".

BTW, "紅色的毛衣" here can be simplified as "紅毛衣".

Comment: Is the `中` also used in this context in Simplified Chinese or it's only used in Traditional Chinese? And thank you for the tips on `红色的毛衣`!

Comment: Yeah, it's less common to use "中" in such context in Mainland text.

Answer (score 0):

这些狗 these dogs

里 among

有一只 one (there is one)

穿 wear

红色(的) red (的 means that 红色 is a adj.)

毛衣 sweater

And the whole sentence is:

"There is one dog among these dogs wear red sweater"

Answer (score -1):

Split the sentence as below to make better understanding

这些狗里 有一只 穿红色的毛衣.

But usually it would be more likely like below in speaking:

(在)这些狗里(面) 有一只 穿红色的毛衣

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepeted. It doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @deutschZuid, oh, I had accepted the answer by user58955, and am not sure why this was altered. Maybe I happened to tap the button when I browse in my iPad. Now fixed, thanks.